# How to get jquery funcionality on touch devices?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile

In the example below `el` is resized gradually by `1px` while a user keeps mouse button pressed
How to get this functionality on touch devices ?
Jquery mobile is deprecated
Do I need a plugin, library or... whatever and what is the corresponding  event ?
Some code example would be appreciated

```js
var el = $('#el');

function go_wplus(){
    let x = el.width() + 1;
    el.width(x);
}

var int;

el.on('mousedown', function(){
    int = setInterval(go_wplus, 100);
}).mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(int);
});
```

```css
.el{position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:50px; height:50px; background:orange; cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='el' id='el'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `touchstart` and `touchend` events on touch devices correspond to the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events on desktop devices, respectively.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried. It works but without `keeping pressed` event. I must repeatidly press and release, just as common click event. How to get the `keeping pressed` event ?